# How to login user through all routes with flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm stuck in a loop, I have a web app, the login and signup was made using Flask on the Backend and Jinja for templating, no JS was used for these two routes, I used WTForms for form validation and Flask Login to handle login .

Now, when user login he is redirected to a dashboard, the dashboard is a single page application that use React, I send HTTP request to my API which is built in Flask (same app, but different blueprints).

The problem is that these APIs routes are avalable only for authenticated users, so I used a token system to authenticate API calls from the client to the server .

To do so, I created a request loader for my login manager, that using a token parameter in the query would decode it , get the email and password and return the respective User, otherwise if it fail it returns None

```
@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user(request):
    if "token" in request.args:
        decoded_token = base64.standard_b64decode(request.args["token"])
        email = decoded_token.split(b':',1)[0]
        password = decoded_token.split(b':',1)[1]
        possible_user = User.select().where(User.email == email)[0]
        if possible_user.password.encode() == password:

            return possible_user
        else:
            return None
    else:

        return None
    return None
```

This token is sent to the user when he login and  get redirected to the dashboard :

- User login successfULY
- Get redirected to dashboard
- Dashboard make an ajax call to "/user-data" , which is protected, this route should use `current_user` to encode the token and send it back to dashboard single page app to use it in further API calls .

**The problem**:

When I request the "/user-data" through AJAX from dashboard, `current_user` is empty thus, the call return a 401 unauthorized request even though the user did login, and in the login route, when I print `current_user` I get the current user logged in as expected . So my question is how can I keep some way to exhcange credentials between login and "user-data" route ?  I tried storing the data in a session in the login route then re-use it in the '/user-data' but the session becomes empty whenever 'user-data' is called .

Here's 'user-data' route :

```
@auth_bp.route("/user-data")
@login_required
def user_data():
    # Return Base 64 encode username:password to use in API calls!
    print("Current user")
    print(current_user)
    print(session)
    code = base64.standard_b64encode(current_user.email.encode() + b':' + current_user.password.encode())
    print(base64.standard_b64decode(code))

    return code
```

Comment: Did you import `current_user` from flask-login, or you have your own implementation?

Comment: @Klimenkomud Yes I did, when I print `current_user` I get `AnonymousUserMixin` in "/user-data" but in Login I get the id of the current logged in user . and I'm making sure to call "/user-data" after login in the user

Comment: I didn't understand your problem: in `user-data` you have your user info, where is any problems?

Comment: @Klimenkomud that's what should happen, but when I call it I get a 401 unauthorized, the current_user doesn't contain the authenticated user anymore, thus I'm unable to retrieve my user data through the route